# Mockito test cases for foreach loop

Tags: java

I have an arraylist and I am converting it into another arraylist of different type using foreach loop. I want to write test cases using mockito. How can I do it?

```
List<Product1> list1 = new ArrayList<Product1>();
List<Product2> list2 = new ArrayList<Product2>(); 
list1.foreach(productList1 -> list2.add(new Product2(product1.getName())));


class Product1{

}

class Product2{
    String name;
    public Product2(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: seeing as Product1 has no getName(), I'm curious this even compiles.

Comment: why do you want to use Mockito? You are using List and POJO, nothing there requiring Mockito for testing

Comment: @Stultuske the code written is for giving an idea. If you are considering its compilation, the lists and iterator both are written vaguely, you should have raised this part also.

Answer (score 1):

You dont' need mocking here. You can write a simple test such as

```
@Test
public void testListConversionForEmpty() {
  assertThat(theConvertingMethod(emptyListOfProduct1), is(emptyListOfProduct2));
}
```

And then you go in, and add more test methods that act on lists with real content.

In other words: you **only** use mocking frameworks when creating "real" objects is too complicated.

In your case, you should simply instantiate a few Product1 and Product2 objects, put them into lists, and make sure that your conversion code delivers the expected results. Meaning: you can fully control the input *without* mocking anything.

( for the record: `is()` up there is a [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/tutorial) matcher )

Comment: Even assert is not required. Flow will go normally. Thanks for the answer btw.